# Can I catch shiny Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-go

In other Pokémon games, you can catch shiny Pokémon if you are lucky. Can I catch shiny Pokémon in Pokémon Go?

Comment: The game's APK as of version 0.29.0 does not contain any static assets that make Pokemon shiny, nor have I been able to find the star that supposedly represents a Shiny Pokemon. However, that doesn't mean the game doesn't have a filter of effect to shinify Pokemon.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Prior to March 22, there were no shiny Pokemon in the game. After this update, it was possible to catch a Shiny Magikarp, which can could later be evolved into a Shiny Gyarados. It was first reported by users on the Sylph Road Reddit, then confirmed [via photographic evidence](http://heavy.com/games/2017/03/shiny-gyarados-in-pokemon-go-photos-pictures-where-found-evolved-color-where-stats/).

Since then, other Shiny Pokemon have been included in the game. Here is the current list:

- Pikachu
- Raichu
- Magikarp
- Gyarados
- Sableye
- Shuppet
- Banette
- Duskull
- Dusclops
- Mawile
- Absol
- Snorunt
- Swablu
- Altaria

Comment: As it stands, the answer is now out of date. A few more shiny Pokemon were released during the Halloween event. I can confirm Duskull is one of them, but I do not know about the others

Comment: we might want to make this answer into a community wiki so it can be properly updated with the game.

Comment: Now the list of shiny Pokemon is quite large, and will only get larger. I'm not sure a list of shiny Pokemon is something we actually want to maintain since it will almost certainly be out of date about as often as it's accurate.

Answer (score 8):

As of right now, there have been no shiny Pokemon encountered in Pokemon GO. As the game has been release for multiple days, more than 8192 Pokemon have been encountered by the install base of multiple hundreds of thousands. Its incredibly unlikely that there are shiny Pokemon in Pokemon GO.

Comment: This is no longer valid.  See [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/303943/163757).

Answer (score 6):

EDIT: Here's an online list of shinies that is updated regularly: https://www.imore.com/pokemon-go-shiny

Posting an updated answer since [the old one is outdated](https://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/pokemon-go-shinies-list). Legendaries are in italics, as they both can't be found in wild in normal circumstances and require higher stardust to trade for.

**Kanto Pokedex:** All Pokemon can be obtained as shiny. Mew, however, can only be obtained as shiny if you participated in the Pokemon Go Tour: Kanto and complete both the Kanto Tour Special Research and the All-in-One 151 Masterwork Research.

**Jotho Pokedex (incomplete)**

- Chikorita and its evolution line
- Cyndaquil and its evolution line
- Totodile and its evolution line
- Togepi, Togetic, and Togekiss
- Natu and its evolution line
- Marill, Azumarill, and Azurill
- Mareep and its evolution line
- Sunkern and its evolution line
- Snorunt and its evolution line
- Misdreavus and its evolution line
- Murkrow and its evolution line
- Pineco and its evolution line
- Snubbull and its evolution line
- Swinub and its evolution line
- Delibird
- Houndour and its evolution line
- Smeargle (previously available, cannot currently be caught as shiny)
- *Raikou*
- *Entei*
- *Suicune*
- Larvitar and its evolution line
- *Lugia*
- *Ho-Oh*
- *Celebi* (requires access to the Distracted by Something Shiny research questline)

**Hoenn Pokedex (incomplete)**

- Pooychena and its evolution line
- Zigzagoon and its evolution line
- Taillow and its evolution line
- Wingull and its evolution line
- Makuhita and its evolution line
- Sableye
- Mawile
- Meditite and its evolution line
- Aron and its evolution line
- Plusle
- Minun
- Spoink and its evolution line
- [Roselia, Budew and Roserade](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/9utdkk/shiny_budew_can_be_hatched/)
- Feebas and its evolution line
- Wailmer and its evolution line
- Swablu and its evolution line
- Shuppet and its evolution line
- Duskull and its evolution line
- Absol
- Wobbuffet and Wynaut
- Snorunt, Glalie, and Froslass
- Luvdisc
- Beldum and its evolution line
- *Latias*
- *Kyogre*
- *Groudon*

**Sinnoh Pokedex (incomplete)**

- Shinx and its evolution line
- Drifloon and its evolution line

Also some from the Unova, Kalos and Galar Pokedexes

**Other**

- Meltan and its evolution line

Comment: I commend the effort, but since this list will most certainly change periodically and the number of shiny Pokemon is quite large and will only become larger, massive list answers like this are challenging to read and maintain. It might make more sense to link to a credible resource that already curates this data and can do so more easily than we can.

Comment: I took your suggestion and highlighted my link which is mostly up to date (missing Pidgey and Rattata, but I'm sure it'll be added). Part of my reason for posting that whole list was that a small answer with a link is more likely to be missed in favour of large good but out-dated answers. Answers can be editted by high rep users too, though ideally a community answer is best for answers like this so more people can edit it.

Comment: Typo for Eevee: Evolutions -> [Eeeveelutions](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Eeveelution) ;)

Comment: Haha! I added it in - couldn't resist! Btw it's Eeveelutions :P

Comment: while it is neat to have a list of them, my question doesnt actually ask for a list. it just asks if any exist/are they catchable.

Comment: You're right. I saw the top answer had an outdated list of shinies, and thought to post an updated version

Answer (score 1):

It's VERY easy to reskin in this game and, as far as I checked, the game files contain no shinies. Sorry guys, the only reskins you might see have been made by some people who want attention.

Comment: How would this attract attention to people? If you reskin your Pokemon on your device, I'll never see that since my skins are unaltered.

Comment: @Ellesedil I think he means that people might reskin their game and take screenshots for attention.